# Not able to see Business Central web application after deploying application from https://start.jbpm.org/

Tags: drools, jbpm, kie

I have downloaded the application using https://start.jbpm.org/ and followed steps-

In the zip I got three projects and build all one by one.

1. business-application-kjar
2. business-application-model
3. business-application-service

In business-application-service I executed

> launch.sh clean install under business-application-service

I see that application started successfully with following logs **but I don't see the Business Central UI**

```
About to install containers '[KieContainerResource [containerId=business-application-kjar-1_0-SNAPSHOT, releaseId=com.company:business-application-kjar:1.0-SNAPSHOT, resolvedReleaseId=null, status=STARTED]]' on kie server 'KieServer{id='business-application-service'name='business-application-service'version='7.31.0.Final'location='http://localhost:8080/rest/server'}'
2020-02-21 23:55:16.648  WARN 92992 --- [           main] o.d.c.kie.builder.impl.KieProject        : No files found for KieBase defaultKieBase
2020-02-21 23:55:16.755  INFO 92992 --- [           main] o.k.s.s.jbpm.JbpmKieServerExtension      : Container business-application-kjar-1_0-SNAPSHOT does not include processes, jBPM KIE Server extension skipped
2020-02-21 23:55:16.757  INFO 92992 --- [           main] o.k.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl   : Container business-application-kjar-1_0-SNAPSHOT (for release id com.company:business-application-kjar:1.0-SNAPSHOT) successfully started
2020-02-21 23:55:16.772  INFO 92992 --- [           main] o.k.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl   : KieServer business-application-service is ready to receive requests
2020-02-21 23:55:16.821  INFO 92992 --- [           main] o.k.s.s.a.KieServerAutoConfiguration     : KieServer (id business-application-service) started successfully
2020-02-21 23:55:17.055  INFO 92992 --- [           main] org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl       : Setting the server's publish address to be /
2020-02-21 23:55:17.273  INFO 92992 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 (http) with context path ''
2020-02-21 23:55:17.278  INFO 92992 --- [           main] com.company.service.Application          : Started Application in 11.848 seconds (JVM running for 12.476)
```

http://localhost:8090/ is showing below message in nice UI

```
Welcome to your Business Application!
Application has successfully started
with following capabilities:

Business Automation

Covers features for process management, case management, decision management and optimisation.


Decision Management

Covers decision and rules related features (backed by Drools project)


Business Optimization

Covers planning problems and solutions related features (backed by OptaPlanner project)
```

At http://localhost:8090/rest/server/ I can see the following XML about Kie Server info

```xml
    <response type="SUCCESS" msg="Kie Server info">
    <kie-server-info>
    <capabilities>KieServer</capabilities>
    <capabilities>BRM</capabilities>
    <capabilities>BPM</capabilities>
    <capabilities>CaseMgmt</capabilities>
    <capabilities>BPM-UI</capabilities>
    <capabilities>DMN</capabilities>
    <location>http://localhost:8080/rest/server</location>
    <messages>
    <content>
    Server KieServerInfo{serverId='business-application-service', version='7.31.0.Final', name='business-application-service', location='http://localhost:8080/rest/server', capabilities=[KieServer, BRM, BPM, CaseMgmt, BPM-UI, DMN]', messages=null', mode=DEVELOPMENT}started successfully at Fri Feb 21 23:55:14 PST 2020
    </content>
    <severity>INFO</severity>
    <timestamp>2020-02-21T23:55:14.911-08:00</timestamp>
    </messages>
    <mode>DEVELOPMENT</mode>
    <name>business-application-service</name>
    <id>business-application-service</id>
    <version>7.31.0.Final</version>
    </kie-server-info>
    </response>
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://start.jbpm.org/ you can download only spring-boot base kie-server. business-central is not shipped with it.